# How to make ghostscript not wipe PDF metadata

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Ghostscript wipes the PDF metadata like `author, title, subject` etc. How can I tell ghostscript not to touch the metadata? I invoke it as follows:

```
gs \
  -dBATCH                    \
  -dNOPAUSE                  \
  -sOutputFile=<output_file> \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite          \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook       \
  <input_file>
```

Comment: Why are you using Ghostscript? There's probably another way to do whatever you're doing. It's uncommon to use Ghostscript when the input isn't a Postscript file.

Comment: @Gilles To down-sample the images in the PDF and thus reducing the size. I don't think it's uncommon to use PDF as input. The tool `pdf2ps` e.g. uses ghostscript for the conversion and is shipped together with `gs`.

Comment: Ok, Ghostscript does seem to be the usual way to downsample images in a PDF file, the open source native PDF manipulation tools seem to be lacking in that regard. That or ImageMagick, which only looks at the images and won't care about PDF metadata.

Comment: ImageMagick uses ghostscript for processing PDFs.

Comment: @Gilles: *"It's uncommon to use Ghostscript when the input isn't a Postscript file."* -- Not at all, Gilles! I use it all the time, every day to do PDF->PDF processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible to keep the PDF metadata when using
ghostscript. Here is a workaround which first saves the metadata to
a file using `pdftk`, then compresses the file with `ghostscript`
and finally writes back the metadata also using `pdftk`.

```
INPUTPDF=<input_file>
OUTPUTPDF=<output_file>
TMPPDF=$(mktemp)
METADATA=$(mktemp)

# save metadata
pdftk "$INPUTPDF" dump_data_utf8 > "$METADATA"

# compress
gs                       \
  -q                     \
  -sOutputFile="$TMPPDF" \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite      \
  -dNOPAUSE              \
  -dBATCH                \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook   \
  "$INPUTPDF"

# restore metadata
pdftk "$TMPPDF" update_info_utf8 "$METADATA" output "$OUTPUTPDF"

# clean up
rm -f "$TMPPDF" "$METADATA"
```

**Edit:** This is a bug in ghostscript, see [Bug report](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693400) and the [confirmation that this is not supposed to happen](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.lang.postscript/2012-10/msg00018.html).

Comment: pdftks dump_data(_utf8) literally outputs Chinese labels. I couldn't find a forum for pdftk either :(

Answer (score 0):

Use exiftool to copy the metadata from the original file.

```bash
exiftool -tagsFromFile input.pdf  output.pdf
```